# Django allauth redirects back to sign up page after email verification (which also fails)

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have a weird issue using Django allauth. The sign up works and sends an email verification email, after I click the verification link sent via email I am redirected to the email confirmation page. The problem is once I click "confirm" to confirm my email I am redirected back to the sign up page and the verification appears to fail as well (no error is thrown). When I go to login as the newly created user another verification email is sent and the cycle repeats itself.

I have tried to configure my settings to redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Settings.py

```
#django-allauth registraion settings
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS =1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = False
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'  # Or whatever you want to redirect to after email verification

  
# 1 day
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('testingland.urls')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    #all_auth_package
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your settings.py from

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS =1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = False
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'  # Or whatever you want to redirect to after email verification
```

To:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS =1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5 
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True 
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = False 
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET= True 
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION= True LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET=True ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL='/'
```